# You have already activated X, but your Gemfile requires Y

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

When running `rake` I get this error:

> You have already activated rake 0.9.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.

Using `bundle exec rake` instead of just `rake` seems to work, but is it the best way to fix this?

Comment: This is also what makes [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) such a great tool. It would allow you to have a separate set of gems for each of these projects so you wouldn't have to worry about this happening again.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Using `bundle exec` *is* the right way to do this.

Basically what's happening is that you've updated rake to 0.9.2 which now conflicts with the version specified in your Gemfile. Previously the latest version of `rake` you had matched the version in your Gemfile, so you didn't get any warning when simply using `rake`.

Yehuda Katz (one of the original Bundler developers) explains it all in [this blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right).

To avoid typing `bundle exec ...` all the time, you could set up an alias or function in your shell for commands you commonly use with Bundler. For example this is what I use for Rake:

```
$ type bake
bake is a function
bake () 
{ 
    bundle exec rake "$@"
}
```

Comment: The blog post doesn't really explain much. The real question is: why doesn't the virgin ruby get the _right_ dependencies and why _then_ complain about having the wrong ones?

Answer (score 174):

Try `bundle clean --force`

It removes every system gem not in this bundle

Comment: ran into this error in RubyMine when running rspec, bundle clean --force, and then RubyMine will automatically install the corrected versions when running rspec again.

Comment: This wasn't enough for me, a `gem update` of the concerned gem helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 73):

**If you have a reason to keep the current version** of rake (or whatever other gem is causing the problem), [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393129/834216) is correct, the best way to do this is to run `bundle exec`. This uses the version specified in your Gemfile instead of using the newest version of the gem you have installed. *(nathan.f77 has a good solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965005/834216) if you don't want to type `bundle exec` every time you run rake)*

Otherwise, if there is no reason not to update rake, you can run

```
bundle update rake
```

This will actually update your Gemfile.lock to use the newest version of rake instead of having to run `bundle exec` every time.

**Note:** if you run just `bundle update` this will update all the gems in your Gemfile instead of just rake, which probably isn't what you want, because if something breaks in your application you won't know which gem update caused it.

---

The less recommended way to keep the older version without having to use `bundle exec` is to uninstall the newer versions of rake.

```
$ gem uninstall rake

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rake-0.8.7
 2. rake-0.9.2
 3. All versions
> 2
Successfully uninstalled rake-0.9.2
```

This works, but if you are working with multiple apps that use different versions of rake, this can be a pain because you will find yourself constantly having to install and uninstall different versions.

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason, there was only one version (0.8.7) installed. So first I did `gem install rake`. Then `gem uninstall rake` and chose 0.9.2.

Comment: ```bundle update``` will also update any gems without versions specified to the latest version available. That may not be what you want. ```bundle update rake``` would be more precies.

Comment: I have the same problem with `public_suffix` instead of `rake`. Running `bundle update public_suffix` has no effect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 15):

Last time that this happened to me, I had updated all my gems.  I did a `gem uninstall rake` and it listed version options. I picked the newer one, and then I did not have to use `bundle exec` anymore.

Basically, if you use `bundle exec` it uses whatever gem version is in installed by your bundle, so what is in the Gemfile.  Without `bundle exec` it uses whatever version is your system default.

Answer (score 10):

Ooh! The Katz article is excellent!

I like this solution the best:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

so that you can now type

```
bin/rake .stuff.
```

For someone like myself who is developing both 2.3 and 3.0.9 apps, this makes me feel a lot better.

Answer (score 9):

`bundle exec` is correct, but you don't want to be typing it every time.

You can put this in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
# Automatically invoke bundler for rake, if necessary.
rake() { if [ -e ./Gemfile.lock ]; then bundle exec rake "$@"; else /usr/bin/env rake "$@"; fi; }
```

Comment: To clarify, the .bashrc file is probably located in your home directory [~/.bashrc]. 

This file gets loaded every time you open up a new terminal window.

Answer (score 6):

Just used: `bundle update`

In my case, it solved my dependency version problem with Gemfile.lock file, it updated the packages with the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Here is the documentation for `bundle update`: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html

Answer (score 2):

You might as well want to delete the Gemfile.lock file and run
`bundle install` or just `bundle`, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there are different version in Gemfile and Gemfile.lock, in mycase am having strscan (3.0.3) in Gemfile.lock and ruby 3.0.4 in Gemfile, just delete the Gemfile.lock and run bundle install or bundle update

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, for some reason, the latest versions of gems must be installed.
Sometimes, there is the need to run older projects based on older versions.
Sometimes, the fastest way to solve those kinds of problems is to delete `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle exec`. That will generate a new `Gemfile.lock` with gems that we have actually installed.
If everything is working correctly, this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to not type it every time is with a Makefile, for example

```
rake :
    bundle exec rake
```

Answer (score 0):

the error already says what to do here. as it suggests that the gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. but the other rake version is already activated. so use

```
gem list
```

command to list all the gem file. then see what gemfile you want to delete. In your case it is rake 0.9.2 . so delete this by going into the folder.

```
cd /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems
```

and delete the desired folder.
then update the gem with this command.

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2

gem install rake -v 0.8.7