# You have already activated rake 0.8.7, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Consider using bundle exec.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I Just moved to site 5 after creating my application offline.  I am having problems with rake. When i try to run **cd ~/MYAPP/; rake db:migrate --trace RAILS_ENV='production'**

I get the following error

**You have already activated rake 0.8.7, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Consider using bundle exec.**

When i try to unistall rake 0.8.7 I get the following warning.

```
addressable-2.2.6 depends on [rake (>= 0.7.3)]
    execjs-1.2.6 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
    execjs-1.2.4 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
    friendly_id-3.3.0.1 depends on [rake (~> 0.9.2)]
    launchy-2.0.5 depends on [rake (~> 0.9.2)]
    multi_json-1.0.3 depends on [rake (~> 0.9)]
    orm_adapter-0.0.5 depends on [rake (>= 0.8.7)]
    rack-1.3.2 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
    rack-1.2.3 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
    rack-mount-0.8.3 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
    railties-3.1.0 depends on [rake (>= 0.8.7)]
    railties-3.0.9 depends on [rake (>= 0.8.7)]
    sprockets-2.0.0 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
    therubyracer-0.9.4 depends on [rake (~> 0.9.1)]
    thor-0.14.6 depends on [rake (>= 0.8)]
    treetop-1.4.10 depends on [rake (>= 0)]
```

I have seen a lot of articles about uninstalling one. When i remove rake 0.9.2 i get an error

*no such file to load -- rake/dsl_definition*

When already have the following in my rake file.

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
require 'rake'
```

Has anyone solved this problem,  I have tried all too

[You have already activated X, but your Gemfile requires Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317980/bundle-rake-error)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to run this command:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace RAILS_ENV=production
```

In this way you should launch your command with the pack of gem bundled with your app.

Comment: I have tried this and i get WARNING: 'task :t, arg, :needs => [deps]' is deprecated.  Please use 'task :t, [args] => [deps]' instead.
    at /home/mysite/stage/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/sunspot_rails-1.2.1/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:41
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted! production database is not configured

Comment: Do you have database.yml in prodution? is it configured?

Comment: This what i have in my 'production:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: true
database: dbformysite_
pool: 5
username: dbusername
password: mypassword
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock'  so i guess the answer is yes.

Comment: Works well in production but when i loaded it to Site5 hosting i can't migrate my db.

Comment: Tried that too, when i do that i get 'You have requested:
  rake = 0.8.7

The bundle currently has rake locked at 0.9.2.
Try running `bundle update rake`
'  Then when i run bundle update rake , Updating .gem files in vendor/cache
  * rake-0.8.7.gem
Removing outdated .gem files from vendor/cache
  * rake-0.9.2.gem
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.   I then run bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace RAILS_ENV='production' i get no such file to load -- rake/dsl_definition. I actually have require 'rake/dsl_definition'
require 'rake'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3847/discussion-between-vezu-and-matteo-alessani)